# Programmatically Exclude Java File in Source Path in Build Path?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I have some list of wrong package java files. I want to exclude this files in my build path programmatically.

Comment: What does it mean programmatically? Why don't you tell Eclipse to exclude it from the build?..

Comment: i want some think like this "IClassPathEntry.addExclusionPattern(IPath)".

Comment: Why programmatically?

Comment: I have some error package java files in my java project. So i will find error package java files then added to excluding in build path

Comment: Oh I read eclipse (and not eclipse-plugin) by mistake, now everything is clear. Sorry for interrupting.